# Are there data-scraping frameworks that handle the archiving, storage of data?

Tags: database-design, screen-scraping, web-scraping, data-mining

I do a lot of web-scraping and for each project I find myself rewriting a kind of framework/backend that involves saving raw pages/files into namespaced directories, and sometimes even a database to keep track of dates, error messages, etc.

I was wondering if there were any such frameworks that have already been built for this kind of task. I don't mean for the actual scraping task itself, which is a combination of using HTML parsers like Nokogiri/Mechanize/etc...but for the management of scrapers and the data they collect. For some of the tasks I do, there's stages in the data-collection.

For example:

1. Iterate through a site, download raw pages
2. Parse the stored raw pages, extract data
3. Clean the data (this can involve other external processes that may not be possible in stage 2)

So any system that helps me keep track of when scrapers started, how they did, and where they saved the raw data is great. I thought of writing my own thing using MongoDB but I'm sure someone has done this better than I have.

Comment: Note that data mining is the analysis, not the gathering of data.

Comment: Nutch stores its data in Solr, if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

I know irobotsoft scraper solves all these problems.  It has plenty of functions to clean html pages and store data, with internal sorting and database operations built in with a simple UI.

Also, it is free.